# How to show/hide div tag based on the user permission

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage, spsecuritytrimmedcontrol

I have used custom div for share icon.When admin login to the site the share icon will be shown.and other user login to the site the share icon will be hidden.how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SharePoint Security Trimmed Control` as mentioned at **[Hide SharePoint 2013 Ribbon based on Permissions](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/hide-ribbon-sharepoint-2013-using-css/)**

Also, you can use a `SPServices` to hide DIV with its ID if the current user belongs to a specific group as the following:

## Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $().SPServices({
 operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
 userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
 async: false,
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  
 //If the current User does belong to the group "SharePoint Group Name"
 if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Qassas Group']").length != 1)
 {
 // where circle1 is the id of div 
 document.getElementById('circle1').style.display = "none";
 } else
 { 
 document.getElementById('circle1').style.display = "block";
 } 
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

> For more details, Please check **[Show / Hide a Div based on a user group in SharePoint via SPServices](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-div-based-user-group-in-sharepoint-via-spservices/)**

---

Also, you can use SharePoint Security Control

Comment: I don't know why it not working on my Page.  Could You show Divs ?

Comment: make sure that the div has id and put it here document.getElementById('divID').style.display = "none";

Comment: Yes my Div has got id="sdiv", and I puted  document.getElementById('sdiv').style.display = "none";

Comment: Please, please help.

Comment: sure let me double check in my side also please tell me are you referenced jquery from the internet or you downloaded the file then reference it

Comment: <div id="sdiv">

Comment: are you replaced your group name at if (xml.search('GroupName') == -1)

Comment: yes My grup name is ABC: if (xml.search('ABC') == -1) And still the page is showing

Comment: Here is all my Code: script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

   //If the current User does belong to the group "Service desk Operators"
    if (xml.search('ABC') == -1)
     {
       // where body is the id of div   
       document.getElementById('sdiv').style.display = "none";
       }  
    }
 });
});
</script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55973/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-grzegorz-z).

Comment: Great Solution :) :)

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution will depend on where you put the DIV tag (e.g. Masterpage (HTML vs. .NET), Page Content, Content Editor Web Part).

You should look into the SPSecurityTrimmedControl.  Here are some links that will help you:

[SPSecurityTrimmedControl class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx)

[How to: Add a Security Trim snippet in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822366.aspx)